# Scrolling to the end of chat list in Whatsapp webpage using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

I am trying to scroll down to the last contact in Whatsapp Webpage chat list using selenium python.

I am receiving the following error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

and sometimes:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

Here is the code:

```
#Trial 1
# driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000);")

#Trial 2
# html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
# html.send_keys(Keys.END)

#Trial 3
# driver. execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")

#Trial 4
#This class is related to the side div 
# test2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='_1C2Q3 F-0gY']")
# driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();',test2) #tried this
# test2.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN) # and also this

#Trial 5
#This class is related to the contacts
recentList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='N2dUK']")
# driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()',recentList) #tried this

for list in recentList :
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", list[:-1] )
    # driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', list)
    # time.sleep(1)
    # driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500);")

    # print('RECENT LIST')
    print(list.text)
```

**My question:**

How to scroll to the end of the chat list in whatsapp webpage

Answer (score 0):

I same problem in whatsapp. I Solved with this code:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pane-side').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

I send the complete code, I tested it and it works:

**import libraries:**

```
import tempfile
import time

from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

**Logical base:**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/') 
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(25)

phone=[] 
date=[] 
msg=[] 

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5.5

while True:

    elements = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(lambda driver:driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="lhggkp7q ln8gz9je rx9719la"]')) 
    
    #driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="g0rxnol2 _3fGK2"]').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pane-side').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

    rep=0
    
    for element in elements:
        #print(interesado)
        elem1 = element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="_21S-L"]').text 
        #print(contenido1)
        if elem1 not in phone:
            phone.append(elem1)
            print(elem1)
            
            elem2=element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/span[@class="aprpv14t"]').text 
            date.append(elem2)
            #print(elem2)
            
            elem3=element.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="vQ0w7"]').text 
            msg.append(elem3) 
            #print(elem3)
        else:
            rep+=1

    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    if rep > 2:
        print('exit infinite loop')
        break
```

**Print results:**

```
import pandas as pd 

result=[phone,date,msg] 
df=pd.DataFrame(result).T

print(len(phone))
print(phone)

df.columns=['PHONE','DATE','MESSAGE']

df
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well and not sure why that RaZieRSarE solution is not working for me. But I am able to solve it with:

```
all_chats = []
all_divs = []
all_temps_name = []
all_temps_div = []
all_inds1 = []
all_inds2 = []
stop_count = 0
step = 0

while True:

    chts = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@role="listitem"]')
    for cht in chts:
        cn = cht.find_element(By.XPATH, './/div[@class="_21S-L"]//span[@class="ggj6brxn gfz4du6o r7fjleex g0rxnol2 lhj4utae le5p0ye3 l7jjieqr _11JPr"]').text
        if cn not in all_temps_name:
            n1 = cht.get_attribute("style").split(': ')[1].split('; ')[0]
            n2 = cht.get_attribute("style").split(': ')[-1].replace('translateY(', '').replace('px);', '')
            all_temps_name.append(cn)
            all_temps_div.append(cht)
            all_inds1.append(int(n1))
            all_inds2.append(int(n2))

    temps1 = [x for _, _, x in sorted(zip(all_inds2, all_inds1, all_temps_name))]
    temps2 = [x for _, _, x in sorted(zip(all_inds2, all_inds1, all_temps_div))]
    for tmp1, tmp2 in zip(temps1, temps2):
        if tmp1 not in all_chats:
            all_chats.append(tmp1)
            all_divs.append(tmp2)

    try:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", all_divs[-1])
        time.sleep(0.01)
    except:
        pass
    
    if stop_count < len(all_chats):
        stop_count = len(all_chats)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

try the below code :

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
```